# How can I add layers in Here maps?

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I want to do something like the following line of code but using HERE javascript API

```
var polygonLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer("PolygonLayer");
map.layers.insert(polygonLayer);
```

I read the documentation but I am not sure if my code is correct. This is my code:

```
var polygonLayer = new H.map.layer.Layer("PolygonLayer");
        map.addLayer(polygonLayer);
```

Comment: [You could read the documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.24.0/dev_guide/topics/vector.html)

Comment: do you really need a new layer for your polygon objects, or you just want to add polygon objects on the map?